# mysql syntax error only when executed by php

Tags: php, mysql

I got this request:

```
"START TRANSACTION; DELETE FROM `awaiting_auth` WHERE `code` = '06b8465eed00727a1eac49fae89b88f876ded2eb' LIMIT 1; INSERT IGNORE INTO `prsn` SET `login` = 'new_user', `passwd` = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef', `color` = '#cbc5f2'; COMMIT;"
```

And I receive this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE FROM awaiting_auth WHERE code =
>   '06b8465eed00727a1eac49fae89b88f876de' at line 1".

However when executing sql via terminal everything goes well and no errors are thrown.
What is wrong with my request? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `mysqli_error($conn)` and see what you get

Comment: how you execute this using php? post relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must split the queries in separate ->query() calls. The SQL console does that automatically. E.g.

```
->query("START TRANSACTION");
->query("DELETE FROM...");
```

Answer (score 0):

One operation per query. So you need to split your query into single queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just run these queries one by one, not in single packet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute each statement individually:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM `awaiting_auth` WHERE `code` = '06b8465eed00727a1eac49fae89b88f876ded2eb' LIMIT 1;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `prsn`(`login`, `passwd`, `color`) VALUES('new_user','40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef', '#cbc5f2');
COMMIT;
```